$\operatorname{det}(Z_0T_0 + Z_1T_1 + Z_2T_2) = 0$ defines a complex curve $C$ with kernel as holomorphic line bundle
This is Exercise 12.4. Riemann Surfaces (Simon Donaldson).

Let $T_0, T_1, T_2$ be generic $n \times n$ complex matrices. Show that the equation $\operatorname{det}(Z_0T_0 + Z_1T_1 + Z_2T_2) = 0$ defines a complex curve $C$ in the projective plane of degree $n$ and that the kernel of $Z_0T_0 + Z_1T_1 + Z_2T_2$ defines a holomorphic line bundle over $C$.

Treating the term generic informally, we can have the following discussions.
Assume $T_0, T_1, T_2$ are generic in the sense that there are no special symmetries or degeneracies (like being scalar multiples of each other, or sharing eigenvectors) that might simplify or trivialize the problem.
The projective plane $\mathbb{CP}^2$ consists of the set of all triples $[Z_0 : Z_1 : Z_2]$ not all zero, up to scalar multiples. The curve $C$ is defined by the equation $\det(Z_0T_0 + Z_1T_1 + Z_2T_2) = 0$.
Degree of the Curve: The determinant $\det(Z_0T_0 + Z_1T_1 + Z_2T_2)$ is a polynomial in $Z_0, Z_1, Z_2$. Since each $T_i$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, $Z_0T_0 + Z_1T_1 + Z_2T_2$ is also an $n \times n$ matrix, and its determinant is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in $Z_0, Z_1, Z_2$. Hence, $C$ is a curve of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$.

Kernel as a Line Bundle: For a point $[Z_0 : Z_1 : Z_2] \in C$, the matrix $Z_0T_0 + Z_1T_1 + Z_2T_2$ is singular (by definition of $C$). Therefore, it has a nontrivial kernel. The kernel of this matrix can be viewed as a line in $\mathbb{C}^n$, varying holomorphically with $[Z_0 : Z_1 : Z_2]$.

Constructing the Line Bundle: Each point in $C$ gives rise to a 1-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$, providing a fiber of a line bundle over $C$. Since the matrix entry functions are holomorphic in $Z_0, Z_1, Z_2$, the assignment of the kernel of the matrix $Z_0T_0 + Z_1T_1 + Z_2T_2$ to each point $[Z_0 : Z_1 : Z_2]$ is also holomorphic. The line bundle is therefore holomorphic.


However, I have no idea how to find exactly what is required of generic matrices here.
